# Returning a loaded GLTF object before adding it to the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, javascript-objects, gltf

I have been trying various ways to do something like this:
I want to load a model and then have the function return it

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;

var loadedModel = loader.load('model.gltf', function (data) {
    var object = data.scene;
    return object;
}
```

then call another function and pass `loadedModel`:

`loadToScene(loadedModel);`

Further, I want it to load to the scene as many times as I want:
Let's just hardcode it for twice here:

```
function loadToScene(model){
model.position.set(0,0,0);
scene.add(model);
model.position.set(0,0,5);
scene.add(model);
}
```

I couldn't find a way to preserve the `data.scene` once the scope of `loader` ends.
Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to call `loadToScene` after your .gltf file has loaded, you need to do it *inside* the callback function:

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;

loader.load('model.gltf', function (data) {
    var object = data.scene;

    // Use loadToScene function *inside* the callback
    // since we don't know when it will finish loading
    loadToScene(object);
}
```

And to add the model twice to the scene, you need to [clone it](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.clone) first. Otherwise, adding the same object to the scene twice doesn't do anything:

```
function loadToScene(model){
    // Add original object
    model.position.set(0,0,0);
    scene.add(model);

    // Clone a copy
    var model2 = model.clone(true);
    model2.position.set(0,0,5);
    scene.add(model2);
}
```